# EF query fails without Convert.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a query similar to the following.

```
var adjustments = DbContext.StorageAdjustments
    .Where(a => a.StorageId == id && a.TimeStamp >= start)
    .Select(a => new StorageUpdateModel
    {
        // Maps properties from the StorageAdjustments table to the StorageUpdateModel.
        TimeStamp = a.TimeStamp,
        Change = a.Quantity,
        Product = a.Product.Name,
        UpdateType = StorageUpdateType.Adjustment,
        UpdateData = Convert.ToString(a.UserName),
        UpdateData2 =Convert.ToString(a.Comments),
        Id = 0,
    });

var trucks = DbContext.StorageTrucks
    .Where(t => t.StorageId == id && t.TimeStamp >= start)
    .Select(t => new StorageUpdateModel
    {
        // Maps properties from the StorageTrucks table to the StorageUpdateModel.
        TimeStamp = t.TimeStamp,
        Change = -t.Quantity,
        Product = "",
        UpdateType = StorageUpdateType.Truck,
        UpdateData = (t.Truck.BillOfLading.HasValue && t.Truck.BillOfLading.Value>0 ? Convert.ToString(t.Truck.BillOfLading.Value) :""),
        UpdateData2 = (t.Truck.ManualEntry ? "True" : "False"),
        Id = t.TruckId,
    });

var railcars = DbContext.StorageRailcars
    .Where(r => r.StorageId == id && r.TimeStamp >= start)
    .Select(r => new StorageUpdateModel
    {
        // Maps properties from the StorageRailcars table to the StorageUpdateModel.
        TimeStamp = r.TimeStamp,
        Change = -r.Quantity,
        Product = "",
        UpdateType = StorageUpdateType.Railcar,
        UpdateData = ((r.Railcar!=null && r.Railcar.RailcarNumber!=null)? Convert.ToString(r.Railcar.RailcarNumber) : ""),
        UpdateData2 = "",
        Id = r.RailcarId,
    });

// Union all three queries into a single query.
var query = adjustments
    .Union(trucks)
    .Union(railcars)
    .OrderByDescending(u => u.TimeStamp)
    .AsQueryable();

var results = await query.ToListAsync();
```

When it executes, an exception is thrown.

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Unable to translate set operation when matching columns on both sides have different store types.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplySetOperation(SetOperationType setOperationType, SelectExpression select2, Boolean distinct)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplyUnion(SelectExpression source2, Boolean distinct)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateUnion(ShapedQueryExpression source1, ShapedQueryExpression source2)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at RailtraxCore.Pager.<ApplyFilterAsync>d__23`1.MoveNext() in D:\Users\jwood\source\repos\Railtrax\RailtraxCore\Pager.cs:line 117
```

But if I change the line:

```
Product = a.Product.Name,
```

To:

```
Product = Convert.ToString(a.Product.Name),
```

Then no exception is thrown!

`a.Product.Name` is already a string. Can anyone offer any ideas as to how `Convert.ToString()` is making the difference?

*Note: Nullable reference types are disabled on this page. Both `StorageUpdateModel.Product` and `a.Product.Name` are type `string` (not `string?`). `a.Product.Name` is a required column. And I'm using EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.3.*

Comment: Why are you using it for `a.UserName` and `a.Comments` or is that just the same issue with different columns?  And what is the exact type of those columns in the DB?

Comment: @juharr: Yes, same issue. They are both strings. Trying to keep things simple by just focusing on `a.Product.Name`.

Comment: C# is a language of types. You don't provide the class definition for `StorageUpdateModel.Product` or `a.Product.Name`. Are they the same? Are you using nullability? Is `a.Product.Name` nullable? What LINQ are you actually using - LINQ to Entity Framework and LINQ to Entity Framework Core are very different, and also need the version.

Comment: @NetMage: Nullable reference types are disabled here. Both `StorageUpdateModel.Product` and `a.Product.Name` are type `string` (not `string?`). `a.Product.Name` is a required column. Using EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.3.

Comment: It looks like you have run into a design flaw in EF Core: it will be fixed in EF Core 8 (see [#19129](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129) ) but I am not sure if it will be patched in EF Core 7. There was a final decision to not check on the EF Core side and let SQL worry about it.

Comment: @NetMage: Yes, but I still don't understand exactly what `Convert.ToString()` is doing. I've been Googling around, and I found the issue on GitHub. But I cannot explain how `Convert.ToString()` resolves this.

Comment: Since you are doing a `Union`, EF Core doesn't care about `StorageUpdateModel` and its types - it will work on the types assigned to each property. The current EF Core set operations implementation checks that the SQL types match so the type of `a.Product.Name` in the database is presumably something like `nvarchar(30)` and the type of `""` is `nvarchar(max)` so they do not match and it throws the (incorrect) exception. The `Convert.ToString` converts the implied SQL type to `nvarchar(max)` and they now match.

Comment: @NetMage: Yes, that sounds right. Googling, I was able to find `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()`, but not any mention of how `Convert.ToString()` is handled by EF. But, seems pretty obvious that EF understands and translates `Convert.ToString()`.

Comment: Note for the next time...  If you do your _Googling_ and find stuff that seems close and possibly relevant, include it in your question (a summary and a link would probably be good enough).  No sense having a bunch of folks all turning up the same info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66789248/861716

Comment: +1 on Null-ability, though from memory EF would normally handle that better but are there cases where the Product for a given row is #null?? You could try something like this to determine if there is a weird null handling issue: `Product = a.Product?.Name ?? "".` EF 6 before nullable reference types would just return #null if a Product wasn't found or didn't have a Name. Now /w EF Core 7??

Honestly Nullable reference types are bound to be a bugbear going forward as while your code might forgive them, implementation details in EF and other libraries may be a bit more pedantic.

Comment: Sadly, EF Core has provider specific function mappings without a required minimal set of translated methods, but assuming you are using SQL Server, here is the [documented function mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#conversion-functions) for the SQL Server provider. You can see that `Convert.ToString` casts to `nvarchar(max)` which is compatible with string literals. If there was a way to cast the string literal to a particular `nvarchar(n)` to match EF Core's understanding of the database column definition, that would work but I am not sure how.

Comment: @NetMage: That's a great find. Thanks! If you feel like writing this up as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Entity Framework ensures that all columns match when doing `Union()`s. This even includes the maximum length for strings (e.g. `NVARCHAR(50)`).

This is the reason for the `Unable to translate set operation when matching columns on both sides have different store types.` exception here.

However, `Convert.ToString()` will convert the string to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#conversion-functions)). As a result, Entity Framework considers the columns to be compatible.

What's less clear is why Entity Framework blocks the first case when clearly this can be made to work.

Comment: The conclusion is wrong. SQL itself requires that matching columns in a UNION have the same type and will either convert them implicitly or through an error. Such queries are usually a sign of design bugs (why were different types used for the same thing?) or *cause* bugs, as numbers or dates may get converted to text using the wrong format

Comment: In this particular case there seem to be multiple design issues. The ambiguous `UpdateData` and `UpdateData2` properties are holding completely different things. That's an OOP issue. Then the LINQ query is trying to convert the two different uses into a SQL query. The first query is trying to load a Bill of Lading, the other a Railcar number, when the table fields have different types. It would be better to have *separate* queries loading only what's needed and map the results to `StorageUpdateModel` using eg Automapper or Mapperly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Someone inside Microsoft told me the restriction was Entity Framework. This is a known issue, which a number of people have complained about. `UpdateData` and `UpdateData2` are both strings. And we know they can be made compatible because I made them compatible with `Convert.ToString()`.