# Concatenate Entity Framework Core models in linq query that are derived from different size varchar columns

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Details: using linq method syntax, and database-first Entity Framework Core models.

Database is SQL Server.

I have 3 tables, the columns from first two tables are of datatype `varchar(256)` and corresponding entity property has data annotation `StringLength(256)`. The column from the 3rd table is defined as `varchar(20)` and corresponding entity property has data annotation `StringLength(20)`.

Query:

```
ThingList = await ctx.Table1.Select(t1 => t1.Thing)
            .Concat(ctx.Table2.Select(t2 => t2.Thing))
            .Concat(ctx.Table3.Select(t3 => t3.Thing))
            .Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

The query works when I concatenate only the first two tables, but then doesn't work when I try to include the third. I'm assuming this is because of the difference in sizes.

How do I get around this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming Table 1, 2, and 3 are related you can just project the concatenation using a simple string operation. `ThingList = await ctx.Table1.Select(i => i.Thing + i.Table2.Thing + i.Table3.Thing).ToListAsync();` Assuming Table 2 and 3 are related directly to table one, if Table3 is related to Table2 then `... + i.Table2.Table3.Thing` If they are unrelated tables then it doesn't make any sense to try and concatenate strings for many Table1s where there could be many unrelated Table2s and/or Table3s.

Comment: @StevePy: The tables are not related in our database. The data is imported from another system and it might be related there, but not in ours. My goal is to find all the unique values in the 'Thing' columns across all three tables combined. So if the string "Hello" appears in all the 'Thing' columns in all three tables i only get one "Hello" string in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what the issue is. This is a known problem:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24707
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129
[EF query fails without Convert.ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75881716/ef-query-fails-without-convert-tostring)

Fixed my issue by changing my query to this:

```
        ThingList = await ctx.Table1.Select(t1 => Convert.ToString(t1.Thing))
            .Concat(ctx.Table2.Select(t2 => Convert.ToString(t2.Thing)))
            .Concat(ctx.Table3.Select(t3 => Convert.ToString(t3.Thing)))
            .Distinct().ToListAsync();
```