# Union with projection: error when running tests using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a union of two `IQueryable` with projection to the same view model type and ordering. This is working for the actual application which is using SQL Server. However, my integration tests are now failing with SQLite.

```
// Example entities

public class EntityA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string EntityASpecificLabel { get; set; } = "";
}

public class EntityB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string EntityBSpecificLabel { get; set; } = "";
}
```

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string EntityASpecificLabel  { get; set; } = "";
    public string EntityBSpecificLabel { get; set; } = "";
}
```

```
// Query
var queryA = context.EntityAs
                    .Where(...)
                    .Select(x => new ViewModel
                             {
                                 Id = x.Id,
                                 Name = x.Name,
                                 EntityASpecificLabel = Convert.ToString(x.EntityASpecificLabel),
                                 EntityBSpecificLabel = ""
                             });

var queryB = context.EntityBs
                    .Where(...)
                    .Select(x => new ViewModel
                             {
                                 Id = x.Id,
                                 Name = x.Name,
                                 EntityASpecificLabel = "",
                                 EntityBSpecificLabel = Convert.ToString(x.EntityBSpecificLabel)
                             });

queries = queryA.Union(queryB)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                .ThenBy(x => x.EntityASpecificLabel)
                .ThenBy(x => x.EntityBSpecificLabel);

var result = await queries.ToListAsync();
```

Everything works on the actual app. But tests are failing using SQLite.

Exception trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplySetOperation(SetOperationType setOperationType, SelectExpression select2, Boolean distinct)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplyUnion(SelectExpression source2, Boolean distinct)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateUnion(ShapedQueryExpression source1, ShapedQueryExpression source2)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at LinqKit.ExpandableQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

After trying different variations I found out that the culprit is with the different sources of `EntityASpecificLabel` and `EntityBSpecificLabel` in the ViewModel projection. When those lines are commented out, as well as in the ordering, the query runs fine.

```
// This incomplete query is working
var queryA = context.EntityAs.Where(...)
                             .Select(x => new ViewModel
                             {
                                 Id = x.Id,
                                 Name = x.Name
                             });

var queryB = context.EntityBs.Where(...)
                             .Select(x => new ViewModel
                             {
                                 Id = x.Id,
                                 Name = x.Name
                             });

queries = queryA.Union(queryB).OrderBy(x => x.Name);

var result = await queries.ToListAsync();
```

How to deal with this inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: No point tagging SQL Server if you want a solution in SQLite.

Comment: It's throwing here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/99d0c74454b683a2d432968794b4627dee6b41e3/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/SqlExpressions/SelectExpression.cs#L2317 ... So is the `Convert.ToString` considered a client side expression in sqlite? Can you eliminate that?

Comment: `Convert.ToString` looks completely unnecessary and likely isn't supported/translated in the SQLLite provider. String to string should just be `EntityASpecificLabel = x.EntitySpecificLabel` If the type in the associated entity isn't a string, `.ToString()` should be supported by most if not all providers. Ideally integration tests should run using the same DB Engine that production would be using as there are bound to be provider specific deltas.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman @StevePy, the `Convert.ToString` is required to get the actual application working (SqlServer). Without that I get "Unable to translate set operation when matching columns on both sides have different store types." But you are right, removing that actually fixes my tests (SQLite), but now breaks my app.

Comment: The `Convert.ToString` workaround is based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72618123/1828662

Answer (score 1):

My colleague found a workaround that plays well with both SQL Server and SQLite. Posting here as it could be useful for others facing a similar situation.

To assign an empty string in the projection, the trick is to use a property that has the same backing data type as what's in the other projection and then applying `.Substring(0,0)`. `Convert.ToString` is no longer required.

Note that this only works when both `EntityA.EntityASpecificLabel` and `EntityB.EntityBSpecificLabel` have the same DB type.

```
// Projections with workaround to ensure matching types across union
var queryA = context.EntityAs
    .Where(...)
    .Select(x => new ViewModel
             {
                 Id = x.Id,
                 Name = x.Name,
                 EntityASpecificLabel = x.EntityASpecificLabel,
                 EntityBSpecificLabel = x.EntityASpecificLabel.Substring(0, 0)
             });

var queryB = context.EntityBs
    .Where(...)
    .Select(x => new ViewModel
             {
                 Id = x.Id,
                 Name = x.Name,
                 EntityASpecificLabel = x.EntityBSpecificLabel.Substring(0, 0),
                 EntityBSpecificLabel = x.EntityBSpecificLabel
             });

queries = queryA.Union(queryB)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                .ThenBy(x => x.EntityASpecificLabel)
                .ThenBy(x => x.EntityBSpecificLabel);

var result = await queries.ToListAsync();
```